# Decomposing Hilbert space into orthogonal complements

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm revising some elementary theory about Hilbert spaces and there is a question that's been bugging me. A common theorem which you find in many books is the following: given a closed subspace $W$ of a Hilbert space $H$, we can decompose $H$ into the direct sum of $W$ and its orthogonal complement: $H = W \oplus{{W^\perp}}$.

Now as far as I can tell $W^\perp$ will be a closed subspace regardless of whether $W$ is closed or a subspace. Using the projection theorem, we can then write $H = W^\perp \oplus{({W^\perp})^\perp}$. So the only 'advantage' we gain by requiring that $W$ is closed subspace is that $W=({W^\perp})^\perp$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Actually $(W^\perp)^\perp$ is always the closure of the span of $W$ for any subset $W$.

Comment: @Berci thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct. If $W$ is not closed, $H = W \oplus{{W^\perp}}$ is not necessarily true: just take a dense subspace ($W=C[0,1]$, when $H=L^2[0,1]$, say), and you'll have $W^\perp=\{0\}$, and $H \neq W \oplus{{W^\perp}}=W$.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I know it's not true, but $H = W^\perp \oplus{({W^\perp})^\perp}$ is still true.

Comment: Second sentence of second paragraph.